# unable to open encrypted database using amitshekhar

Tags: android, database, sqlcipher-android

Hello I am using  this library since long but without sqlcipher now I have converted my database into sqlcipher and followed all steps which are defined here https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database , after application launch when ever I open IP for its showing shared prefences data correctly but when I click on my sqlcipher database it shows nothing and getting log also

In Build.gradle

```
 debug {
             resValue("string", "DB_PASSWORD_Obee_MVP", *****")
```

libraries implemented

```
debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db-encrypt:1.0.6'
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

When i click on my database I am getting this in logs too

2021-04-22 13:24:05.712 7274-7372/com.xxx.xxxE/ClientServer: Exception.
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:89)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:62)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:91)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:48)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:60)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:2016)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1902)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.keyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:2669)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseInternal(SQLiteDatabase.java:2599)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1247)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1214)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1186)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1135)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1336)
at com.amitshekhar.debug.encrypt.sqlite.DebugDBEncryptFactory.create(DebugDBEncryptFactory.java:15)
at com.amitshekhar.server.RequestHandler.openDatabase(RequestHandler.java:187)
at com.amitshekhar.server.RequestHandler.getTableListResponse(RequestHandler.java:306)
at com.amitshekhar.server.RequestHandler.handle(RequestHandler.java:113)
at com.amitshekhar.server.ClientServer.run(ClientServer.java:77)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Comment: anyone here for guideline?

Comment: still looking for solution